# Application on Unreal engine stops rendering when I disconnect my monitor

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an application that was made on Unreal engine and for some reason when I disconnect my display (HDMI cable) it suddenly stops rendering/refreshing screen. Even if I connect to my PC via TeamViewer the application doesn't start rendering picture until I plug HDMI cable back in. Does anyone know what exactly causes this (unreal engine/windows/GPU drivers or something else) and how can I make this application to render picture at all times with and without HDMI cable plugged in?

I am using Windows 10 Pro (21H1) and my PC has 3070 FE.

Update: I tried to connect both computers to the same monitor and instead of unplugging HDMI cable, I used switch source option on my monitor, this seem to do the trick. But I am curious if I can achieve the same without having HDMI cable plugged into my video card

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear I tried to not disconnect HDMI cable and then I tried to disconnect it.. there isn't a lot I can research. I have no control over this application and I have next to no knowledge about how Windows or GPU drivers work hence I am looking for some pointers here